# Installed Python Upgrade and Deleted My Apple OS Packages

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I upgraded my native python 2.7 to `Python 2.7.15` and now all of the native packages that came with my MacOS are gone when I do `pip freeze`.

Is this concerning and if so, what should I do. No time machine backups.

I know touching the native python is a no-no but didn't realize the upgrade would delete all packages.

Comment: it shouldn't delete them. Try typing 'python 2.7' in a terminal window and tell me what you get?

Comment: how did you upgrade?

Comment: I get the following error: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '2.7': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @jmh I followed the "Install Python from Source" [here](http://stackabuse.com/install-python-on-mac-osx/)

Comment: what if you type 'locate python2.7'?  No space after python..

Comment: I get this: `WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.`